# Xcode warning for call to DispatchQueue.main.sync: Call to method 'asd' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit

Tags: swift, cocoa, foundation, dispatch-queue

When calling `DispatchQueue.main.async` or `DispatchQueue.main.sync` with a call to `self` without capturing `self`, I get a compiler error:

```
Call to method 'asd' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit
```

Since I usually use `DispatchQueue.main.async`, I'm now used to solving this error by capturing `self`, which unfortunately doesn't seem to work with `DispatchQueue.main.sync`:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        asd() // no warning or error
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.sync { [self] in
        asd() // warning: Call to method 'asd' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit; this is an error in Swift 6
    }
}
```

This warning only appears for `DispatchQueue.main.sync` and *not* for `DispatchQueue.main.async`. Why? How can I avoid having to prefix every method call with `self.` in this case?

Comment: Don't ever think about calling `DispatchQueue.main.sync`. Main queue is a serial queue. If you do it like that, it will block the queue and at the same time the queue is waiting for tasks to be executed, so it will cause a crash.

Comment: It will only cause a crash if called from the main queue itself, but I'm calling this from a background thread which I forgot to mention.

Comment: @son It's perfectly fine to call `DispatchQueue.main.sync` as long as you do it from a queue other than `main`.

Comment: @Nickkk Use `self.asd()` instead of (or in addition to) adding `[self] in`.

Comment: I made a hasty decision at the very first look. My bad. I see global queue now.

Comment: Which closure is the warning about? `DispatchQueue.global().async {}` or `DispatchQueue.main.sync {}`?

Comment: It's `DispatchQueue.main.sync`, as indicated by the code comment.

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.sync` is the inner closure, is the warning about the outer closure? Where is `[self] in` added when you let Xcode fix it?

Comment: The warning is displayed on the same line as the comment in the code. Xcode offers two fixes: 1) `Reference 'self.' explicitly` which changes the line of the warning to `self.asd()` and also makes the warning disappear, 2) `Capture 'self' explicitly to enable implicit 'self' in this closure` which changes the first line to `DispatchQueue.global().async { [self] in` but doesn't make the warning disappear, and this time there are no suggested fixes.

Comment: Somehow the warning magically disappeared in my test app after a clean build. Maybe i'm using a different version.

Comment: It happens whenever I paste the code in a new project.